# AngularJS: Creating a New Form in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a new form in Angular so in the NewRequestController, I am setting up a $scope object with the defaults for the form and blanks for the form fields.

Here is the new controller:

```
var NewRequestController = function($scope){
    $scope.web = [];

    $scope.web['Title'] = "";
    $scope.web['Site'] = "";
    $scope.web['Priority'] = "";
    $scope.web['Division'] = $scope.current_user.Division;
    $scope.web['Requestor'] = $scope.loggedInUser.Title;
    $scope.web['CreationDate'] = new Date();
    $scope.web['CustomerDueDate'] = "";
    $scope.web['Page'] = "";
    $scope.web['Instructions'] = "";
```

And here is my form:

```
<form name="newWebForm" role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label for="description">
            Description: <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Description" ng-model="web.Title">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Description -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="site">Site Affected:</label>
            <select name="site" class="form-control" ng-options="w.ID as w.Title for w in websites" ng-model="web.Site">
            <option>Please Select ...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="priority">Priority: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <select name="priority" class="form-control" ng-options="p.ID as p.Title for p in Priorities" ng-model="web.Site">
            <option>Please Select ...</option>
            </select>
            </div>
    </div> <!-- Site / Priority -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label for="dueDate">Division:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" name="Division" ng-model="{{web.Division}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label>Requestor:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" name="requestor" value="{{web.Requestor}}">
         </div>
    </div> <!-- Division / Requestor -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="create_date">Creation Date:</label>
            <input type="text" id="create_date" class="form-control datepicker" disabled="disabled" ng-model="{{}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="dueDate">Due Date: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Click to choose a date" ng-model="{{due_date | date : 'MMM dd, yyyy'}}">
        </div>
    </div> <!-- CreationDate / DueDate -->

    <div class="row" ng-show="due_date < forward14Days">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="reason_rushed">Reason for Rushed Service: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <textarea name="reason_rushed" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Reason Rushed -->

    <div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label for="pages">Page / Site URL (if applicable):</label>
            <textarea name="pages" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Page / Site -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label for="event_notes">Instructions: <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="instructions" class="form-control" rows="5">{{web.Instructions}}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Instructions -->

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px;">
        <div class="form-actions col-lg-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click=createNewWeb($event)>SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Submit -->    
</form>
```

I tested it in the browser and had 13 errors like `Token web.Division is unexpected` and `Unable to set property 'Title' of undefined or null reference` The unable to set property Title is particularly confusing to me because, of course, its null .. the form hasn't been filled out yet.

Am I doing something wrong? OR Are Angular Form just too difficult to use? If so, what's the alternative if the rest of the app is Angular.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see ng-form...

Comment: The book said that was for nested forms -- googling it now

Comment: var NewRequestController = function($scope){
    $scope.web = {};// Set it with an object instead of an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple things wrong with your setup. It primarily involves your use of `ng-model`. You should never use `{{ }}` with `ng-model`. <del>`ng-model="{{web.Division}}"`</del>. Instead do `ng-model="web.Division"`. That will get you the binding that you're expecting. You have several cases where you are misusing the `{{}}` with a `ngModel`.

Also, don't use filters inside of `ng-model`. Filters like this: `ng-model="{{due_date | date : 'MMM dd, yyyy'}}"` would need to be handled within your controller or in a different way. You can apply this same date formatting using Angular filters inside javascript (as compared to doing it within HTML, refer to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to see how to do it)

As a general rule of thumb, don't use `{{ }}` within any directive that starts with `ng`. Those are Angular directives that are generally already aware of the `$scope`.

The other error that I came in when testing out your code was the assignments of:

```
$scope.web['Division'] = $scope.current_user.Division;
$scope.web['Requestor'] = $scope.loggedInUser.Title;
```

I assume you have those defined somewhere else in your app. I created a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u8pY4fW7susuYG8qjY15?p=preview), and for my purposes I just set `.Division` and `.Requestor` to empty strings.

Comment: Are you saying no {{}} even for text-areas? If so, how do you handle textareas?

Comment: `textarea` can be done with `ng-model`. Docs say that `ng-model` is intended for `input`, `select`, and `textarea` (and custom-made elements as well)